# Finding and deleting lines from all files recursively

Tags: grep, sed

I have managed to grep the occurences of a keyword by using

```
grep "KeyWord" . -r -n -i -I
```

but, the occurences of the KeyWord are too large. I just want to delete all the lines containing that word.

I searched around, sed looks like to be the utility. Can anyone tell me what command would do the trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With a GNU sed:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i /KeyWord/d
```

With an OSX sed:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' /KeyWord/d
```

First command `find` finds all the standard files (not directories, or pipes, or etc.), prints them separated by `\0` (so filenames can contains spaces, newlines, etc.).

Second command `xargs` reads the output of `find`, grabs a list based on a separator (`\0` because of `-0`), invokes `sed -i [...]` with added parameters from the list (`sed` will be called multiple times if there are a lot of files, as the maximum length of the parameters is limited in each invocation).

The `sed` command modifies in-place (`-i`).

As to `/KeyWord/d`, it'll delete lines containing the regular expression `KeyWord`.

You should learn `sed` to properly understand the (simple but unusual) syntax, and refer to the appropriate manpages for more information about the tools involved here.

---

And as I like to promote `zsh`, the solution with its extended globs:

```
sed -i /KeyWord/d **/*(.)
```

Comment: How about just deleting the word "keyword." and not the whole line?

Comment: `s/KeyWord//g` (substitutes `KeyWord` with '' (empty string), `g` for all (not only the first on each line).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
find -type f -exec ex -sc g/KeyWord/d -cx {} ';'
```

1. `g` global search
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close

Comment: in OSX that gave me `find: illegal option -- t` , had to add the `.` 

`find . -type f -exec ex -sc g/KeyWord/d -cx {} ';'`

Answer (score 0):

I originally started with a `grep` to find the files, so it feels a little safer to modify that slightly than to switch to a `find`.

```
$ grep -l -r KeyWord * | xargs sed -i /KeyWord/d
```

`grep -l` will print the filenames, `sed -i` will edit them.